# How to list all loaded Spring bean definition files

Tags: java, spring

In a large enterprise system it's not always clear what files get imported during ApplicationContext construction.
Is there a way to list all the files loaded during the process?
I know how to list property files loaded, but not the imported bean files.

Update with example:

File 1: applicationContext.xml contains line:

```
<import resource="classpath*:importableBeans1.xml" />
```

File 2: importableBeans1.xml contains line:

```
<import resource="classpath*:importableBeans2.xml" />
<import resource="classpath*:importableBeans3.xml" />
```

File 3: importableBeans2.xml contains some bean definitions.
File 4: importableBeans3.xml contains some bean definitions.

After ApplicationContext is loaded I'd like to be able to print something like this in console:

```
applicationContext.xml
importableBeans1.xml
importableBeans2.xml
importableBeans3.xml
```

Comment: It is managed by Spring container and it is on demand(object are created when it is needed). Why you need to know the same?

Comment: I need to see what files are loaded as part of the application startup. I don't need beans, just the files.

Comment: You mean resources(like .properties) file or any file like .java too?

Comment: I updated my question with some more information. I want xml files only. Please take a look above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When starting a `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` or more generally an `AbstractXmlApplicationContext`, an `XmlBeanDefinitionReader` will be used to load your xml files.

Each time an xml file will be loaded, to be precise *before* it gets loaded, you'll have a log (info) from `loadBeanDefinitions(EncodedResource encodedResource)` :

```
    if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
        logger.info("Loading XML bean definitions from " + encodedResource.getResource());
    }
```

If you can't rely on this information you can play with `ReaderEventListener` :

```
public class TrackingImportXmlApplicationContext extends ClassPathXmlApplicationContext {

    private static final TrackingImportReaderEventListener trackingImportReaderEventListener = new TrackingImportReaderEventListener();

    public TrackingImportXmlApplicationContext(String configLocation) {
        super(configLocation);
    }

    public TrackingImportXmlApplicationContext(String... configLocations) {
        super(configLocations);
    }

    @Override
    protected void initBeanDefinitionReader(XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader) {
        super.initBeanDefinitionReader(reader);
        reader.setEventListener(trackingImportReaderEventListener);
    }

    public TrackingImportReaderEventListener getTrackingImportReaderEventListener() {
        return trackingImportReaderEventListener;
    }

    public static class TrackingImportReaderEventListener extends EmptyReaderEventListener {

        private final Set<String> imports = new HashSet<>();

        @Override
        public void importProcessed(ImportDefinition importDefinition) {
            imports.add(importDefinition.getImportedResource());
        }

        public Set<String> getImports() {
            return imports;
        }
    }
}
```

And then :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TrackingImportXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new TrackingImportXmlApplicationContext("/META-INF/applicationContext.xml");
        TrackingImportXmlApplicationContext.TrackingImportReaderEventListener tracking = applicationContext.getTrackingImportReaderEventListener();
        for (String _import : tracking.getImports()) {
            System.out.println(" >>> imported : " + _import);
        }
    }
}
```

In this later solution you'll only have imported file, but of course you already know your initial xml file(s)