# Spring Boot get list of XML files being read in from classpath (using BeanDefinitionReader implementation)

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.3 in an application I am writing. My application is unique in that:

1. I would like to use Spring Boot but also pass an XML file with beans to be loaded as well (I am currently using @ImportResource to do this)
2. I need to capture and store the names (and preferably paths as well) for all XML files being loaded in (the one passed to @ImportResource and any that this file imports)

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32724329/how-to-list-all-loaded-spring-bean-definition-files) except that I am not using `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` and instead I am launching with `SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);`. I am curious about whether there is a way to:

1. Override the XmlBeanDefinitionReader used by Boot or add a listener to it (as in linked SO question, except Boot-style)

I have already tried this by using a custom Reader passed to the `@ImportResource` as `@ImportResource(value=file.xml, reader=CustomXmlReader` where `CustomXmlReader` is an `@Configuration` annotated class, extends `XmlBeanDefinitionReader`, and provides a custom constructor `public CustomXmlReader(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry)` that adds a custom listener. The problem with this was that I got an exception where bean of type `BeanDefinitionRegistry` could not be found.

2. Provide a custom ApplicationContext to be loaded by Boot that does the overriding from #1

I have tried this as well but with no success. I have gotten a ClassPathXmlApplicationContext to load, which would allow me to replicate the linked SO answer, but that context gets dumped during refresh when Boot comes up and I lose access to the info. Plus, I would prefer not to have to load two Spring contexts. Maybe the answer to this is that I need to NOT use Spring Boot, but I would like to find an answer that allows me to keep as much of Boot as possible.

Also, as a side question (perhaps I should ask this in a SO separate question): does anyone know a method to load XML config in Boot *without* using @ImportResource (i.e. using a command line argument or Spring property)?

I can post some limited code examples with my attempts here or on github if needed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE 1:**
From what I can tell, #1 looks like the best option going forward. I got rid of the `BeanDefinitionRegistry` not found Exception by adding an `@Configuration` annotated `public class CustomRegistry extends DefaultListableBeanFactory` (I am not sure if DefaultListableBeanFactory is the best option here). I am able to get a listener registered to capture import events. However, it only captures the first import and not subsequent `encodedResource` XML files loaded by the `XMLBeanDefinitionReader`'s `loadBeanDefinitions(EncodedResource encodedResource)`. What is the best way to capture each of these files as they are loaded?

**UPDATE 2:**
Looks like I was wrong: the event listener captures all imported files from the first file and not the file added in `@ImportResource` annotation. Once I get that file name (assumably from the `CustomXmlReader`) I should be good to go!

**UPDATE 3:**
I took a new approach to gathering all of the file names. Instead of using an event listener on my `CustomXmlReader` I chose to `@Override` the `public int loadBeanDefinitions(Resource resource)` and from here I can easily capture the file names and paths of all XML config files being read in. Now my only problem is that I cannot figure out how to access the `CustomXmlReader` once my application has started up. Any calls to the `ApplicationContext` to get a bean of that type (or trying to `@Autowired` the `CustomXmlReader`) instantiate a new bean and do not return the one used by `@ImportResource`. One step closer...